# Getting error messages when trying to display images from a database while using codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, error-handling, phpmyadmin

I am trying do display information from my database using codeigniter, but I keep reeving an error message. The error messages is `Severity: Warning Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

This is my model:

```
class stuffModel extends CI_Model {
    private $stuff_table = 'Stuff';

function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function getItem()
    {
        $un = array();


        $res = $this->db->get($this->stuff_table);
        $results = $res->result();

        return $results;
    }

}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public function displayStuff() {
$STUFF= $this->stuffModel->getItem();

$this->load->view('myView',array('stuff' => $STUFF));
}
```

And this is my View:

```
<?php
foreach ($stuff as $s) {
echo"<h1>".$s['Items']."</h1>";

}?>
```

And the error message is `Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: stuff` and `Severity: Warning Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: `$STUFF` why is this full capitals?  Just from a convention stand point it looks like (o_O)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is jumping out at me and it looks like it should work. Here's a little trouble shooting idea.

Change the controller as follows

```
public function displayStuff() 
{
   $data['stuff'] = $this->stuffModel->getItem();
   var_dump($data); //share this output here
   $this->load->view('myView', $data);
}
```

Comment: Should be a comment, this isn't an answer, though it will lead him to find his answer ;)

Comment: OK, still get errors but what does `var_dump($data)` show?

Comment: Nothing is shown except the error messages when I added the var_dump

Answer (score 0):

You did not load the model into controller that's why you can't call the model from the controller .

first load the model into controller

```
$this-load->model('modelName');
```

than call

```
$this->modelName->methodName();
```

Comment: I called the model earlier on in my controller, above outside this function I have: function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('stuffMdoel');
 }

Comment: it will only work for every function if you called it into __construct() , either you have to load the model into every single function .

Comment: I did call it in my __constract(), but just now I also called it in my function (so it is being called twice) but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: try to change `private $stuff_table = 'Stuff';` to `protected $stuff_table = 'Stuff';` than try once again.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes in Controller**

Make sure that the object of model class is declared in the constructor as given below

```
$this->load->model('stuffModel', 'stuffModel', TRUE);
```

then in the displayStuff function,

```
public function displayStuff() {
 $data['stuff']= $this->stuffModel->getItem();    
 $this->load->view('myView',$data);
}
```

**Change in the model**

```
public function getItem()
    {
       $res = $this->db->get($this->stuff_table);
        if ($res->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $res->result_array();
        } else {
            return array();
        }

    }
```

**Finally in the view**

You can display the values stored in the array by iterating as follows

```
foreach($stuff as $stf){
echo $stf['field_name'];
}
```